# Is it possible to execute an asp.net web api using korn shell script

Tags: asp.net, shell, unix

We need to check the technical feasibility to call a Asp.NET web api from korn shell script. 
The purpose is to log the start and successful or error end of the script via Web API in a log table. As a bigger picture all the jobs will be using the web API to log the start and end with status. We are creating a Web API to facilitate this.

Can anyone please suggest can this web application be executed or called from Korn shell script. If yes then what command shall be used.

Answer (score 0):

You may use netcat (nc) in order to establish a TCP connection with the web server.